# 'list' object has no attribute 'decode' - Python error

Tags: python, regex, utf-8, urllib

I am having issue decoding some of the data in the string

```
respData = urllib.request.urlopen(
    'https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html')

resp = respData.read()

link = re.findall(r'<ul class="secondary-menu">(.*?)</ul>', str(resp))
# URLS
Urls = re.findall("href=[\"\'](.*?)[\"\']", str(link))

# remove amp from the urls
Url1 = [re.sub(r'amp;', '', item) for item in Urls]
# menu
deals = re.findall(r'<span>(.*?)</span>', str(link))
print(deals)
```

Output:

```
['Deals', "\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85What\\\\\\'s New\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85", '\\\\xc3\\\\x80la carte & Value Meals', 'Crispy Chicken', 'Share Box', 'Happy Meals', 'Desserts', 'McCaf\\\\xc3\\\\xa9', 'Beverages', 'Side Lines', 'Snack Time']
```

I want to change this
`\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85What\\\\\\'s New\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85", '\\\\xc3\\\\x80la carte & Value Meals, McCaf\\\\xc3\\\\xa9'` to `'What's New', 'la carte & Value Meals' ,'McCafe'`
I beleive it has something to do with .decode('utf-8') and I did apply to the line where I am using regex to fetch the deals `deals = re.findall(r'<span>(.*?)</span>', str(link)).decode('uts-8')` but it gives an error:

```
deals = re.findall(r'<span>(.*?)</span>', str(link)).decode('uts-8')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

**Summary:**
I know my problem can be solved by decode('utf-8') but I am unable to apply it properly. Just need help how to decode the data I am fetching in deals

Comment: Are you intentionally applying `re.findall` to stringified lists, or do you not know that `re.findall` returns a list? You must, since you're casting the result to `str`. But why?

Comment: Yes I know it returns a list, The problem here is that i am trying to decode the content saved in deals.

Comment: That's not how it's done. You need to loop through each string in the list then do your additional searching on each of those strings.

Comment: Can you tell me how? It would be great!!

Comment: Another problem you'd be facing is that the page loads via javascript so you'll need something like Selenium to get at the javascript-rendered HTML code.

Comment: Everything else is working perfectly okay. I know I could use beautifulsoup and scrappy to get the data but I am in training and was instructed to fetch the data with regex so my hands are tied here :) It would be great if I could get help with my question, I am really stucked

Comment: See https://repl.it/repls/RundownPlushOperatingenvironment#main.py but again `urllib.request.urlopen` will only return a string full of script tags so you'll need something that understands javascript.

Comment: What If I want to only remove or decode the data in list. As deals has fetch the data how about decoding the data in the list. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the string is encoded so you can see  things like `"\\\\"`, which means `"\"`
`\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85What\\\\\\'s New\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85`is actually `★What's New★`
So we can now deal with it by two steps:

```py
str1 = """\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85What\\\\\\'s New\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85", '\\\\xc3\\\\x80la carte & Value Meals, McCaf\\\\xc3\\\\xa9'"""
str2 = str1.replace("\\\\","\\")
print(str2)

# \xe2\x98\x85What\\'s New\xe2\x98\x85", '\xc3\x80la carte & Value Meals, McCaf\xc3\xa9'
```

then we deal it by:

```py
str1 = b"""\xe2\x98\x85What\\'s New\xe2\x98\x85", '\xc3\x80la carte & Value Meals, McCaf\xc3\xa9'"""
str2 = str1.decode("utf-8")
print(str2)

# ★What\'s New★", 'Àla carte & Value Meals, McCafé'
```

hope it is helpful to you